# WSO2 ESB. Como puedo setear el timeout y demás propiedades de un default endpoint mediante una variable?

Tags: api, variables, requests, endpoint, wso2

Necesito poder pasar una variable a las propiedades de mis default endpoints, ya que me veo obligado a darles distintos valores dependiendo del ambiente en donde se encuentren (dev,qa,pro).
  Algo como la imagen a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no encontré muchas opciones a esto pero me seria de mucha utilidad algunas sugerencia

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar variables del sistema.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="StockQuoteEndPoint">
  <address uri="$SYSTEM:stockQuoteEP"/>
</endpoint>
```

Referencia: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Injecting+Parameters+as+Environment+Variables

Comment: Please answer in spanish, you're at SO en español, also please read [answer] could you provide a most complete answer explaining this please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't speak Spanish. Added the minimal answer without much English in case it helps. Feel free to -1 if need, and I will delete this.

Comment: No problem but you can use Google translator yo help you answering

Comment: thanks bee. la respuesta que me das es valida pero necesito saber si las variables se pueden poner en la propiedades del endpoint, específicamente en donde la imagen que adjunte muestra las palabras "variableN".  Realice la prueba con el ide integrator studio y no es posible insertar variables de tipo --> $system:variableN.